# Raven Db with different LINQ syntax doesn't appear to be working

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am just getting started with RavenDB and have run into a weird scenario.

When I run the following query, the model gets populated just fine.  Everything works great.

```
var contacts = Session.Query<Contact>()
                      .Where(c => c.UserId == this.userId)
                      .ToList();

var model = contacts.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { 
                                     Text = c.FullName, 
                                     Value = c.Id }).ToList();
```

However, that isn't the code I started with.  I started with the code below which populates the Text property from the contact FullName. For some random reason, it doesn't populate the Value property from the contact id.

```
 var model = (from c in Session.Query<Contact>()
              where c.UserId == this.userId
              select new SelectListItem() { 
                         Text = c.FullName, 
                         Value = c.Id }).ToList();
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am just missing something simple. Ideas?

** UPDATE **

It doesn't like this syntax either. I must be missing something really basic here.

```
 var model = Session.Query<Contact>()
                    .Where(c => c.UserId == this.userId)
                    .Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.FullName, Value = c.Id })
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, you've got a `ToList()` call *before* the projection. So the only thing that the LINQ provider needs to worry about is the `Where` call. It will fetch *all* of the data for each `Contact`, and then the projection occurs in LINQ to Objects instead.

In your second code, the `Select` call needs to be handled by the LINQ provider as well - and presumably it's not doing the right thing.

So yes, this sounds like a bug in the RavenDB LINQ provider, in the `Select` handling.

Note that another way of forcing the rest of the query to execute in LINQ to Objects is to use `AsEnumerable()` - so this should work:

```
var model = Session.Query<Contact>()
                   .Where(c => c.UserId == this.userId)
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(c => new SelectListItem { 
                                  Text = c.FullName, 
                                  Value = c.Id })
                   .ToList();
```

(I've converted `new SelectListItem()` to `new SelectListItem` in the object initializer expression too, but that's really a no-op.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't love that we are pulling down all of the data from the document but I guess it will have to work. Assuming the Contact document had lots of data in it, wouldn't you want the Linq Provider to handle the select rather than fetch all of the data?

Comment: @BrettAllred: Yes, absolutely - and I suggest you raise a bug against Raven with your scenario.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the .Id property being null in RavenDB 1.0.960, but not in the current 1.2 unstable build.  Therefore, I would say it's a bug that's been fixed already.  1.2 is getting very close to RTM (according to Ayende), so if you can, I would switch over now.